# Memory consumed by NMaximize with NDSolve

Tags: memory

I'm using `NMaximize` on a function that calls `NDSolve`, and running out of memory. I created the following minimal example that (I think) recreates the problem I'm having, but on a smaller scale.

```
f[t_?NumericQ] := Block[{sol, s, x},
  sol = First[NDSolve[{x''[s] + Sin[x[s]] == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1}, x, {s, 0, t}]];
  x[t] /. sol]

memInit = MaxMemoryUsed[];
ListPlot[Reap[NMaximize[
  {f[t], t < Pi, t > 0}, t,
  Method -> "NelderMead",
  EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[MaxMemoryUsed[] - memInit]]][[2]]]
```

On my machine, with a freshly launched MathKernel, the memory usage increases badly after a run of not increasing at all. Here's the plot:

[image: Memory usage after each evaluation of f]

If I run `NMaximize` on `Sin[t]` instead of `f[t]`, the memory usage does not increase. Can anyone explain the difference in behavior or suggest how to reduce memory usage?

Comment: Furthermore, `NMaximize` seems not to play a role in the memory consuming. (`ListPlot@Reap[Do[f[t]; Sow[MaxMemoryUsed[] - memInit], {t, 100}]][[2, 1]]` shows similar result. ) Then, let's wait for someone else to answer your question :D (The memory management behind `NDSolve` is so complicated that it's beyond my reach. )

Comment: @xzczd I only see it with NMaximize. I ran your Do loop with no increase in memory use at all. (9.0.1.0, MacOSXx86).

Comment: Have you tried it with a fresh kernel? This happens when I start a fresh kernel and run the following 3 lines of code: `f[x_?NumericQ]:=……; memInit=……; ListPlot[……`

Comment: @xzczd Yeah ... tried with a fresh kernel. Thanks for thinking about this one!