# How to delete InterpolationFunction created by NDSolve/ParametricNDSolve?

Tags: memory

I have faced a uncommon problem. The situation is that I need use ParametricNDSolve/ParametricNDSolveValue to solve ODEs system in the non-linear model fitting process. So every iteration generating a new parameter set and create a new InterpolatingFunction object. I guess the older InterpolatingFunction objects are not abandoned and it may be the reason for memory increase rapidly during the process. Now the problem is whether I can clear the objects at every iteration and how to do it.

> For a similar problem, I copy a 4D PDE example from [MathGroup Archive](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Aug/msg00178.html):

```
i = 0;
sol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x, y, z], t] == 
     D[u[t, x, y, z], x, x] + D[u[t, x, y, z], y, y] + 
     D[u[t, x, y, z], z, z], u[0, x, y, z] == 0, 
     u[t, 0, y, z] == Sin[t], u[t, 40, y, z] == 0, 
     u[t, x, 0, z] == Sin[t], u[t, x, 40, z] == 0, 
     u[t, x, y, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, x, y, 40] == 0}, {u}, {t, 0, 
     100}, {x, 0, 40}, {y, 0, 40}, {z, 0, 40}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
    MaxStepSize -> 1, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> If[t > i, Print[{t, MemoryInUse[]/1024^2 // N}];
      i += 10;]]
MemoryInUse[]/1024^2 // N
```

This resulting InterpolatingFunction object will use about 1.5G memory. Clear[sol] is invalid to release its memory. If the PDE is used in model fitting, how to get the final result without memory running out?

Comment: `$HistoryLength = 0` (or some sane small value) might help a bit.

Comment: I have tried the code `$HistoryLength = 0` , and found it's not useful.

Comment: @sejabs: setting `$HistoryLength=0` should help, but you have to do that **before** you run `NDSolve`, it won't help after that has been run. Can you try with a fresh Kernel? For me, setting `$HistoryLength=0` and adding a ';' after the `NDSolve` will make a `Clear[sol]` free most the memory...

Comment: Thanks @Albert Retey and J. M.♦ ! I tried the example with suggestions above: [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40935/memory-consumed-by-nmaximize-with-ndsolve) and got a satisfied zero memory occupied during NMaximize, although it may not be the best solution for the specific problem.

Comment: @sejabs: if you found a solution to your problem, feel free to post it as an answer, AFAIK it is welcomed to answer ones own questions in such cases...

Comment: @Albert Retey, sorry, the edit has 5 minutes limitation. By the way, I use code like this: `workP := Module[{...}, temp = ParametricNDSolve[ odes...,t ], Clear[temp] ]..., ParallelTable[workP]... `. May I need to add `$HistoryLength = 0` into first line of workP to make the parallel kernels to know the command?