# Why does NDSolve and ParametricNDSolveValue show different memory manage in same loop?

Tags: differential-equations, memory

This is a follow-up  question about [How to delete InterpolationFunction created by NDSolve/ParametricNDSolve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100677/how-to-delete-interpolationfunction-created-by-ndsolve-parametricndsolve). In the previous question,  J. M.♦ and  Albert Retey showed $HistoryLength = 0 and Clear[] are uesful to release memory occupied by InterplatingFunction. But in the present question, I found a different memory manage between NDSolve and ParametricNDSolveValue. 
The code is follows:

```
(*NDSolve*)
$HistoryLength = 0;
mpl = 1/Sqrt[6.70837*10^-39];
gsT = 106.75;

Sup[ΛI_?NumericQ, ΓI_?NumericQ] := 
Module[{a, ρr, Trad, tf, s, t, result}, tf = 10/ΓI;
s = NDSolve[{a'[t] == 
  a[t]*Sqrt[(8 π)/(3 mpl^2) (ρr[
        t] + ΛI^4/
         a[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t])], ρr'[t] + 
   4*Sqrt[(8 π)/(3 mpl^2) (ρr[
         t] + ΛI^4/
          a[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t])] ρr[
     t] == ΓI ΛI^4/
    a[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t], 
 a[0] == 1, ρr[0] == 0}, {a, ρr}, {t, 0, tf}];
 {a = a /. s[[1]], ρr = ρr /. s[[1]]};
 result = ρr[tf]*a[tf];
 Remove[tf]; Remove[Trad]; Remove[s]; Remove[a]; Remove[ρr]; 
 Remove[t];
 result]
```

I use more power clean function Remove[] to replace Clear[],  and in the loop

```
Do[Sup[2.2, time], {time, 1, 10000, 0.1}]
```

showing a stable memory which is not increaing. But using  ParametricNDSolveValue with the same equation and loop, it shows a increasing memory.

```
Do[(Module[{s, as}, 
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{a'[t] == 
   a[t]*Sqrt[(8 π)/(3 mpl^2) (ρr[
         t] + ΛI^4/
          a[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t])], ρr'[t] + 
    4*Sqrt[(8 π)/(3 mpl^2) (ρr[
          t] + ΛI^4/
           a[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t])] ρr[
      t] == ΓI ΛI^4/
     a[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t], 
  a[0] == 1, ρr[0] == 0}, {a, ρr}, {t, 0, 
  tf}, {ΛI, ΓI, tf}]; 
  as = s[2.2, time, time/10]; Remove[s]; Remove[as];]), {time, 1, 10000,  0.1}]
```

or

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{a'[t] == 
 a[t]*Sqrt[(8 π)/(3 mpl^2) (ρr[
       t] + ΛI^4/
        a[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t])], ρr'[t] + 
  4*Sqrt[(8 π)/(3 mpl^2) (ρr[
        t] + ΛI^4/
         a[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t])] ρr[
    t] == ΓI ΛI^4/
   a[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t], 
a[0] == 1, ρr[0] == 0}, {a, ρr}, {t, 0, 
tf}, {ΛI, ΓI, tf}];
Do[(Module[{as}, as = s[2.2, time, time/10]; Remove[as];]), {time, 1, 
 10000, 0.1}]
```

So is there a explain?

Comment: @belisarius has settled, thanks! And I have tried to change every global variables to local and remove it in second code, but it's not useful too.

Comment: Some (but not all) leakage can be prevented with `Method -> {"ParametricCaching" -> None}`

Comment: I tried the method `Method -> {"ParametricCaching" -> None, 
  "ParametricSensitivity" -> None}` in the code, it's not useful although. In my opinion, the InterpolatingFunction created by ParametricNDSolveValue can be removed through attached variable. Obviously there is something wrong. Maybe I need to consult with Wolfram staff.

Comment: You could report it to the wolfram support.